# Writing to a binary file in PROLOG

Tags: file, binary, prolog

I know how to write to ordinary files, but I haven't found any resources on the web about binary files in Prolog.

I'm using Turbo Prolog.

Comment: It cannot be done portably, I think. Check out your Turbo Prolog manual, or better, switch to a modern implementation.

Answer (score -1):

ISO Prolog has binary I/O.
Just Google: "ISO Prolog Standard" for anything about ISO Prolog.

Here is an [I/O reference](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/search?for=write&in=man&match=summary) for SWI-Prolog, free, ISO.

*Turbo Prolog* is hard to find documentation for.  If you look at *Example 64* that ships with it, you'll find a way to call C from Prolog.  That'll get you binary I/O for sure.